# Possible experimental errors and how to improve them

Tags: home-experiment

I'm doing an experiment at home where I determine the relative atomic mass of magnesium by collecting the hydrogen produced from its reaction with hydrochloric acid. I ended up getting around 26, but as I know the relative atomic mass of Mg is around 24.3. So I would like to ask whether the following errors can be improved in any way:

1.When I removed the magnesium oxide coating on the surface of the magnesium ribbon, I knew it would affect the result because I couldn't remove all of them.Is there a way to remove all the magnesium oxide coating without having the magnesium metal react?

2.I used a gas syringe to collect the hydrogen. Would applying vaseline to the syringe and the place it connects with a tube actually work （as the syringe moves?)

3.I assumed that the molar volume was 24dm3 when it wasn't exactly room temperature. I looked online and saw an 'ideal gas law'. Could this be applied without having to add extra complicated apparatus to collect data? (pressure?)

Comment: Have you made a correction for the water vapor pressure in the collected gas ?

Comment: Um what is that?

Comment: Focus first on eventual conceptual errors (what and how to measure and calculate) before experimental errors (how well is was done).

Comment: If you want to use $pV = nRT$  in your experiment, you must correct your pressure measurements for the content of water vapor in  the gaz produced by hydrochloric acid aqueous  solution. Suppose the pressure measured on the classroom barometer is maybe $98 000$ Pa, and the temperature is $20°$C. Now, at $20$°C, the water pressure is $2340$ Pa, from the Tables. So the pressure $p$ to be introduced into the formula $pV = nRT$ is : $p = 98 000$ Pa - $2340$ Pa = $95 660$ Pa. With this pressure, the number of moles $\ce{H2}$ is : $n(\ce{H2}) =  pV/RT$,  with $p = 95660$ Pa.